# javascript .click(function() not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created this function in javascript for when an `ahref` link is clicked

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ProcessCharges").click(function() {
        alert("testing");
        if($("#customerbilling_unitprice").val() == "") {
            alert("Please Enter a Unit Price");
            return false;
        }
        if($("#customerbilling_resellercost").val() == "") {
            alert("Please Enter a Reseller Unit Price");
            return false;
        }
        if($("#customerbilling_todate").val() == "") {
            alert("Please Enter a To Date");
            return false;
        }
        if($("#customerbilling_fromdate").val() == "") {
            alert("Please Enter a From Date");
            return false;
        }

        //work out number of days between the two dates
        var tDate = new Date($("#customerbilling_todate").val());
        var fDate = new Date($("#customerbilling_fromdate").val());
        var diff=tDate-fDate;
        var days_between= diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

        //do the cost per month times 12 (months)
        var year_cost = $("#customerbilling_unitprice").val() * 12;
        // RESELLER //
        var year_cost_reseller = $("#customerbilling_resellercost").val() * 12;
        // RESELLER //

        //do the yearly cost / 365
        //this will give the daily cost
        var daily_cost = year_cost / 365;
        // RESELLER //
        var daily_cost_reseller = year_cost_reseller / 365;
        // RESELLER //

        //check number of days
        alert(days_between);
        if(days_between == '29' or days_between == '30' or days_between == '31' or days_between == '0') {
            //its a FULL month
            var total_cost = parseFloat( $("#customerbilling_unitprice").val().toFixed(2) );
            // RESELLER //
            var total_cost_reseller = parseFloat( $("#customerbilling_resellercost").val().toFixed(2) );
            // RESELLER //
        } else {
            //now do the daily cost times cost_per_month
            var total_cost = daily_cost * days_between;
            var total_cost = parseFloat( total_cost.toFixed(2) );
            // RESELLER //
            var total_cost_reseller = daily_cost_reseller * days_between;
            var total_cost_reseller = parseFloat( total_cost_reseller.toFixed(2) );
            // RESELLER //
        }

        $("#customerbilling_unitprice").val(total_cost);
        $("#customerbilling_resellercost").val(total_cost_reseller);
    });
});
```

But when clicking the link, the function is not running. The first thing it should do, is to display the alert box which it is not doing

i have created a fiddle here to show full code: http://jsfiddle.net/0v02nLnc/

Comment: First job of debugging javascript: check the console. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier `. You're using `or` as a keyword in your `if` condition which is incorrect, use `||`

Comment: There's a bug in your code!

Comment: The modified Code  http://jsbin.com/gocoxuwafe/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using incorrect syntax.
Replace your condition

```
if(days_between == '29' or days_between == '30' or days_between == '31' or days_between == '0') {
```

to

```
  if(days_between == '29' || days_between == '30' || days_between == '31' || days_between == '0') {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(days_between == '29' or days_between == '30' or days_between == '31' or days_between == '0') {
```

should changed to

```
if(days_between == '29' || days_between == '30' || days_between == '31' || days_between == '0') {
```